# What do I need exactly

Tags: input-device, output

I have a raspberry pi, but is there a list somewhere of all the other input/output items I need, such as a mouse etc? And can you specify if they need to be wired or not? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Pi Exchange. This site is a Q&A which means you should ask a specific question so that one answer works well. Your question is open ended and does not really fit this site.  Please browse the site to get an idea of things you could do with the Pi. Simple answer is you don't need anything if you don't want to. You can just plug it into networks and SSH into it from another machine. You could also connect everysingle USB device you have lying around. It is up to you. Treat the Pi like a computer. Good Luck and looking forward to some more specific question in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Foundation guides https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/ the [Hardware Guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/hardware-guide/) deals specifically with needed hardware.